# How do I check multiple checkboxes with jquery without giving each an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I am trying to check multiple checkboxes using one with jQuery. I know how to do this to check all checkboxes or to check multiple if they have ids. I want to be able to do this without that though.

All of my checkboxes are in a similar grouping. I have them grouped in a consistant way.

I have my work on a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepd/W75dy/18/).

Here is my code

```
window.onCheck = function () {
var totals = [0, 0, 0];
$('tr.checkRow').each(function () {
    var $row = $(this);
    if ($row.children('td:first').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked')) {
        $(this).find('td.imageBox').each(function (index) {
            var $imageBox = $(this);
            if ($imageBox.children('img:first').attr('src').indexOf('yes') >= 0) {
                ++(totals[index]);
            }
        });
    }
});

$('#total1').text(totals[0]);
$('#total2').text(totals[1]);
$('#total3').text(totals[2]);
};
window.onCheckForm = function (cb) {
var $cb = $(cb);
var $table = $cb.parents("table");
$('input.subFieldCheck').find($table).prop('checked', function () { return cb.prop('checked')});

}
```

My problem is with the onCheckForm function.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest since you're using jQuery to use events the right way, in your JavaScript file, not in the markup. It's messy.

Comment: table elements don't have a 'checked' property. Do $('input.subFieldCheck').find($table).find('input[type="checkbox"]')...

Answer (score 2):

Note: I started writing this answer for a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266369/how-can-i-check-multiple-check-boxes-in-jquery) and realized I couldn't post this, so I posted it here instead. The table structure is different and a lot simplified in this answer.

Lets start off with a very simple table with a checkbox column:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope='col' id='toggler'>
                <input type='checkbox' id='toggleAll'>
                <label for='toggleAll'>Select all</label>
            </th>
            <th scope='col'>A column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td headers='toggler'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
            </td>
            <td>some cell data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers='toggler'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
            </td>
            <td>some cell data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers='toggler'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
            </td>
            <td>some cell data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers='toggler'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
            </td>
            <td>some cell data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers='toggler'>
                <input type='checkbox'>
            </td>
            <td>some cell data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, I have a checkbox in the header along with a label for accessibility purposes (you may hide the label if you wish).

I've also given the header cell an ID and used the `headers` attribute for the `td` elements. This isn't absolutely necessary for what we're doing, however it seems like an appropriate case to use the `headers` attribute. If you ever want to move the checkbox to another column for certain rows, you can just add the `headers` attribute to that cell.

Here is some JavaScript code:

```
$('#toggleAll').change(function () {
    $('td[headers~="toggler"] >  input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

We are binding a function to the `change` event to the checkbox in the header.

The selector will look for all checkboxes that are children of `td` elements that contain the ID `toggler` in a space-separated list of tokens in the `headers` attribute.

The `.prop()` method sets the `checked` property of the checkboxes to match the value of the `checked` property of the one in the header ("this").

Our basic functionality is done here.

We can make improvements though, by changing the state of the checkbox at the top to match the state of the checkboxes in the rows.

The state of the header checkbox should be:

- Unchecked if 0 are checked
- Interdetermine if (0, `n`) are checked
- Checked if `n` are checked

Where `n` indicates all the checkboxes.

To do this, we bind a function to the `change` event of each of the boxes in the table rows:

```
$('td[headers~="toggler"] > input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var allChecked = true, noneChecked = true;
    var headerCheckbox = $('#toggleAll');

    $('td[headers~="toggler"] > input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, domElement) {
        if(domElement.checked) {
            // at least one is checked
            noneChecked = false;
        } else {
            // at least one is unchecked
            allChecked = false;
        }
    });

    if(allChecked) {
        headerCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
        headerCheckbox.prop('indeterminate', false);
    } else if (noneChecked) {
        headerCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
        headerCheckbox.prop('indeterminate', false);
    } else {
        headerCheckbox.prop('indeterminate', true);
    }
});
```

I'm using `.each()` here to loop through all of the appropriate checkboxes to determine whether all, none, or some are checked.

See the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mkJtu/).

Hope this helps, I sure learned quite a bit while answering the question!

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle for a cleaner way:

http://jsfiddle.net/W75dy/19/

```
<td class="field">
    <form class="fieldCheck">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Row1Chk" name="Row1" value="Row1" />
    </form> Programs
</td>

$('#Row1Chk').on('change', function(event) {
    $('table.checkTable input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```